# Why was this question locked rather than deleted?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, locked-posts

I recently encountered the [following question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960546/please-response-help-wanter-copmuter-people):

[image]

I can't see deleted comments, but I'm slightly confused by why this was locked. In its current state, the question makes little sense, so it makes perfect sense for it to be closed, but the OP can't even edit it to improve it.

What is the purpose of this action? Is it to let controversy about the post "die down" a bit before unlocking it? If not, why not just delete it outright?

Comment: If we are discussing a specific post, please try to link to it somehow (inconspicuously if you'd prefer).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56960546/6471538

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yeah, I was mostly trying to avoid targeting the particular diamond and focus on the moderation action itself.

Comment: I am Copmuter people! You wanter me?

Comment: @Davy does that mean you need help with Capchas?

Comment: @Patrice Only with the human legible ones. I have no problem reading those [fully illegible Capchas](https://www.homestuck.com/story/647).

Comment: That's going on a t-shirt.

Comment: Copmuter sounds like a threat against law enforcement officers to me.

Comment: Nowadays, people asking such questions are the ... \*looks at username\* ... well...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Closing & temporary lock is pretty much the same as deleting (since roomba will delete the question after a while), except that it leaves the chance for the OP to edit the question into shape (Of course, given the title here, there was little hope for that)

Locking has been performed after a lot of comments were flagged and the discussion was becoming toxic.

Some moderators (including me) don't like to delete too quickly, as it can be seen as abusing power / censorship, and then the question link is lost. Leaving the question closed & locked (with all heated comments removed) isn't particularly harmful in that case, and everyone can see how bad it is (but not rude or abusive), before it is edited or deleted.

And when it's finally deleted, noone objects. In that case, 3 20k+ users deleted it after it was automatically unlocked.

Comment: "Closing & temporary lock is pretty much the same as deleting" no, it's not. Locking makes impossible for anyone other than moderator to edit the question. If that is your rationale, I don't believe it is a sound one. Closing allows the OP to fix their question, locking doesn't.

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying: deleting is much _worse_ than _temporary lock_. permanent lock is bad. But I'm not talking about permanent lock, but temporary, to let things cool down

Comment: Post deleted can be edited by the post owner and can be flagged (for undeletion, for example). Locks don't allow that, while the lock is in effect. Locking is more frustrating for the post owner, and would more likely give up. As I explained, lock is the worse option out of any possible option. Deletion is preferred at this point.

Comment: the lock has been done to avoid heated comments, but make the question still accessible by everyone. Deletion allows editing, but needs flagging to be undeleted when a moderator deletes.

Answer (score 12):

> What is the purpose of this action? Is it to let controversy about the post "die down" a bit before unlocking it? If not, why not just delete it outright?

That is exactly the reason.

Locked questions automatically are unlocked provided the moderator didn’t permanently lock the question.  It was locked due to the activity in the comment section.

Comment: Just checked the comments, yup, the comments were purged for reasons and the post was appropriately locked.. closure and deletion would also work in this case.

Comment: @SamuelLiew Yeah, I couldn't see the exact comments that triggered the action in the first place.